# Updating the TextBox content

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I've a TextBox binded to a property. Is there a way to update the textBox's content without using

```
RaisePropertyChanged(() => Property);
```

inside the Property?

I want to update the value of the Property1 in another Property2 and then update the value of the TextBox that's binded to Property1 inside Property2.

Is that possible?

Comment: Why don't you just do that then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you may be looking for a PropertyChangedCallback.

The basic sentax is this:

```
static ClassName() 
{
    Property = DependencyProperty.Register("PropertyName", typeof(propertyType), typeof(ownerType), 
    new UIPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(PropertyChangedCallback));
}

static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArts e)
{
    ClassName class = obj as ClassName;
    // Manipulate properties by accessing them through class.
}
```

See this link for more information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745795.aspx